# Dynamics CRM 2011 getting entity has not been modified in post update

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I want to get the not modified entity when PostUpdate event triggered. 
I try to use

> context.PreEntityImages

but it is null.

How to I get this entity in PostUpdate event?

Comment: did you register the entityimage in the plugin registration tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to register a pre-entityimage for the post-update step.

You can then acquire the entityimage using the following code snippet:

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var context = (IPluginExecutionContext) serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IPluginExecutionContext));

    Entity preImage = context.PreEntityImages.First().Value;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Guido Preite and Henk van Boeijen thank you for your responses :)

I didn't register entityimage, it is worked after register entityimage